# Webdriver error when using IE and Jenkins

Tags: internet-explorer, jenkins, webdriver

I was getting this error while using Webdriver in IE9 "Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones".
I was able to avoid this error by instatiating the driver as follow

capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

It worked fine when I was running my test locally But it doesn't seem to work when I trigger them via Jenkins(it gives me the same error again).

Comment: You are introducing the instability by setting the capability, note that that is a desired capability and it may or may not be fulfilled. I would like to know the cause for this behavior though.

Comment: Well set the protected zones correctly on your Jenkins server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set all internet zones to the same level, preferable to the lowest one.

You can do that on Control Panel, Internet, Security, for Internet, Local, Trusted sites, etc.

Sorry I can not be more exact about it, because I am currently on a Mac, but please, try that and it will run.